# InvalidOperationException on Attaching POCO entity to context

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, poco

I'm experiencing a trouble with attaching a POCO entity to its context.  I'm getting an InvalidOperationException with the following message:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

Actually, I only got this exception with a single item.  I did not experience this kind of exception when I attached different items aside from this specific item.

I'm using the following code:

```
 ItemDocument itemDocument = new ItemDocument();
 Item item = GetItem(itemID); // the item I got here is detached
 using (SampleContext context = new SampleContext()){
      context.Items.Attach(item);  // I got the exception here
      context.LoadProperty(item, "Classifications");
      itemDocument.Classification = item.Classifications.Select(c => c.Name).ToList();
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying to [`Detach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.detach.aspx) the old object from context before attaching new one with the same key?

Comment: Actually, the old object is already detached.  I'm also clueless why it's just going wrong with a single item and not with other items.  I guess it's with the Classification navigation property.  When I commented out the line of code that loads that property, I'm not having that problem.

Comment: Isn't `Classification` loaded automatically and you are unintentionally forcing ef to load it again?

Comment: No, it's not loaded automatically.